# What is the transfer function of the filtfilt?

Tags: matlab, filter-design, lowpass-filter, digital-filters, parks-mclellan

I designed a Parks McClellan filter to design a lowpass filter. First, I created the order of the filter with firpmord(). Then I designed the filter with firpm() and created the impulse response. I then filtered my signals with filtfilt() . What I want to learn here is the mathematical equivalent of firpmord(), firpm() and filtfilt() functions. I want to learn what the input-output relations transfer functions are.

Comment: To clarify, you are asking for a mathematical relationship between the inputs to the `firpmord()` function and the transfer function of the filter created when you effectively do the following `filtfilt(firpm(firpmord(args)))`? That's not a question; you're asking somebody else to do a complex derivation for you. The paper here describes the algorithm used by `firpmord()` https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/54_predictability%20of%20fir%20filters.pdf and as you can see it is not linear.

Comment: The MATLAB documentation says this paper has the algorithm for `firpm()`, but I did not find a free pdf copy on the web. If you are a student you may be able to get access to the paper through your school, or purchase it online. "Digital Signal Processing Committee of the IEEE Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing Society, eds. Programs for Digital Signal Processing. New York: IEEE Press, 1979, algorithm 5.1."

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB documentation for `filtfilt()` links to a brief explanation of the concept. It seems they use an anti-causal version of the original filter to "rectify" to zero-phase. I imagine if you multiply the transfer function of your original filter and it's anti-causal counterpart, you will arrive at the total transfer function for the filter.
$$
H_{0}(z) = H(z)H(z^{-1})
$$

https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/anti-causal-zero-phase-filter-implementation.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to ask again because I am confused. I designed FIR filter with Parks McClellan algorithm (firpmord()-firpm()). Then I filtered it with filterfilt() . I did research on the internet. I found such a result. This is the transfer function of the FIR filter, and if I multiply it by the time reselve, do I get the transfer function? I can't even be sure of the transfer function of the FIR filter. [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu0ze.png

Comment: Since this is a substantive change to your question, please _edit your question_ with this new information.  While you're editing, please clarify what you meant when you said "then I filtered it with filerfilt".  Did you mean you filtered the **FIR** filter with `filtfilt`, or that you filtered something else, with the FIR filter definition, using `filtfilt`?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question again. I hope it was clearer this time.